# When to make copy and assign constructors delete in c++11?

Tags: c++11, constructor

I often see the code that deletes 1)copy ctor and 2)assign ctor.

What is the advantage to do so?

I append sample code.

```
class A{
    ...
    private:
        A(const A& copy) = delete;
        A &operator=(const A &assign) = delete;
};
```

Comment: Mistagged as rule-of-three.  The rule of three is concerned with when to define constructors, assignment operators, and destructors, not when to `delete` them.

Answer (score 0):

> It prevents the class from being copied or assigned.

For example it useful when you have a `A` class that has a `m_p` pointer as a member variable which that class owns (`A` class is responsible for deallocation). In this case you can't safely copy or assign the `A` class. Because compiler generated copy constructor and assign operator will share the ownership of that pointer and in destructor when you will want to delete pointer you can get 
a double-delete or access violation from dereferencing a freed pointer.

Comment: That's usually a reason to explicitly define a copy constructor and assignment operator (to ensure a deep rather than shallow copy) not to `delete` them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a case where you don't want to create copies of your class then you restrict that by making the copy constructor and assignment operator `private` or mark them as `delete`.

- This is useful when you want to create a config class or a cache where having multiple copies of your class don't make sense.
- In standard library, strems are not copy constructable and copy-assignable.